Line not appearing on line chart only y-axis and x-axis appear in d3.js linechart
I am trying to create a line graph in d3.js but only my axes are appearing; the line doesn't show.
I think there might be something wrong with how i use the nest but i don't have any idea how to fix it.
This is the current state of what my code shows when execute
enter image description here
Here is the snippet of the code and i use d3 ver 3
  // Define line generator function for Weekday Sales chart
  var lineWeekday = d3.svg.line()
    .x(function(d) { return xWeekday(d.key); })
    .y(function(d) { return yWeekday(d.value); });

  // Render Weekday Sales chart
  var xWeekday = d3.scale.ordinal().domain(totalSalesByWeekday.map(function(d) { return d.key; }))
    .rangeRoundBands([0, width], 0.1);
  var yWeekday = d3.scale.linear().domain([0, d3.max(totalSalesByWeekday, function(d) { return d.value; })])
    .range([height, 0]);

  // Render Weekday Sales line chart
  svgWeekday.append("path")
    .data(totalSalesByWeekday)
    .attr("class", "line-weekday")
    .attr("d", function(d){return lineWeekday (d);})
    .attr("fill", "none")
    .attr("stroke", "blue")
    .attr("stroke-width", 2);
  
  svgWeekday.append("g")
    .attr("class", "x-axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(d3.svg.axis().scale(xWeekday).orient("bottom"));

  svgWeekday.append("g")
    .attr("class", "y-axis")
    .call(d3.svg.axis().scale(yWeekday).orient("left"));

I had tried to make it into array by adding [] in the .data but it gives me error so i'm stuck

.datum() instead of .data() to bind the entire dataset to the path.


 // Sample data
    var totalSalesByWeekday = [
      { key: "Monday", value: 150 },
      { key: "Tuesday", value: 200 },
      { key: "Wednesday", value: 250 },
      { key: "Thursday", value: 300 },
      { key: "Friday", value: 400 },
      { key: "Saturday", value: 500 },
      { key: "Sunday", value: 350 }
    ];

    // Dimensions and margins
    var margin = { top: 20, right: 30, bottom: 50, left: 50 },
        width = 800 - margin.left - margin.right,
        height = 400 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

    // Create SVG container
    var svgWeekday = d3.select("body")
      .append("svg")
      .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
      .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
      .append("g")
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

    // Scales
    var xWeekday = d3.scale.ordinal()
      .domain(totalSalesByWeekday.map(function(d) { return d.key; }))
      .rangePoints([0, width]);

    var yWeekday = d3.scale.linear()
      .domain([0, d3.max(totalSalesByWeekday, function(d) { return d.value; })])
      .range([height, 0]);

    // Line generator
    var lineWeekday = d3.svg.line()
      .x(function(d) { return xWeekday(d.key); })
      .y(function(d) { return yWeekday(d.value); });

    // Render the line
    svgWeekday.append("path")
      .datum(totalSalesByWeekday) // Bind the entire dataset
      .attr("class", "line-weekday")
      .attr("d", lineWeekday);

    // X-axis
    svgWeekday.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x-axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(d3.svg.axis().scale(xWeekday).orient("bottom"));

    // Y-axis
    svgWeekday.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y-axis")
      .call(d3.svg.axis().scale(yWeekday).orient("left"));

    // Add labels
    svgWeekday.append("text")
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + (width / 2) + "," + (height + margin.bottom - 10) + ")")
      .style("text-anchor", "middle")
      .text("Weekdays");

    svgWeekday.append("text")
      .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
      .attr("y", -margin.left)
      .attr("x", -(height / 2))
      .attr("dy", "1em")
      .style("text-anchor", "middle")
      .text("Sales");
.line-weekday {
      fill: none;
      stroke: blue;
      stroke-width: 2;
    }

    .x-axis path,
    .x-axis line,
    .y-axis path,
    .y-axis line {
      shape-rendering: crispEdges;
      stroke: #ccc;
    }
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.17/d3.min.js"></script>



